# Facing issue while passing "ip_addr" in url using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to pass ip_addr (if env = qa, then pass this ip_addr=x.x.x.47 or else ip_addr=x.x.x.53) using ternary operator and also tried using if condition.
When I use ternary operator, I'm getting **operand expected (error token is ""qa"?** error. And, with if condition, error: url is not calling properly and if condition is failing. Could someone help me to fix this issue ? Also, please suggest any other way to fix this issue. Thanks in Advance !

```
##2: Using ternary operator

#! /bin/bash
env=qa
username=testuser
pass=password

ip_addr = $(( $env == "qa" ? "x.x.x.47" : "x.x.x.53"))

export id=`curl -u "$username:$pass" \
-H 'Accept: application/vnd.go.cd.v4+json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/vnd.go.cd.v4+json; charset=utf-8' \
'http://'${ip_addr}':8080/test/api/cases'| grep -i '"id":'`

echo "Expected Id is ${id}"


##2: Using if condition

#! /bin/bash
env=uat
username=testuser
pass=password

if (${env} == "qa"); then
    ip_addr = "x.x.x.47"
else
    ip_addr = "x.x.x.53"
fi

export id=`curl -u "$username:$pass" \
-H 'Accept: application/vnd.go.cd.v4+json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/vnd.go.cd.v4+json; charset=utf-8' \
'http://'${ip_addr}':8080/test/api/cases' | grep -i '"id":'`

echo "Expected Id is ${id}"
```

Comment: Have you tried using https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check your code?  It looks like you may have some issues with use of parenthesis rather than brackets.

Comment: Yeah. I changed the brackets and removed extra space, still my script is failing in both scenarios.

Comment: `$(( foo ? bar : baz ))` works only for **math**, not for strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (${env} == "qa"); then
  ip_addr = "x.x.x.47"
else
  ip_addr = "x.x.x.53"
fi
```

Firstly, what is intended to be the if condition, is actually the request to run `${env} == "qa"` in a subshell. This does not make sense. You need to use double bracket notation, or the `test` builtin. The former looks like:

```
if [[ ${env} == "qa" ]]
```

Secondly, *no* spaces are allowed between *variable*, *equal sign*, and *value* in assignments. It must read:

```
ip_addr="x.x.x.47"
```

The complete if looks like this:

```
if [[ ${env} == "qa" ]]; then
  ip_addr="x.x.x.47"
else
  ip_addr="x.x.x.53"
fi
```